# numpy.nbytes unclear meaning

Tags: python, numpy

From `numpy` documentation:

> numpy.ndarray.nbytes¶ attribute
>
> ndarray.nbytes Total bytes consumed by the elements of the array.
>
> Notes
>
> Does not include memory consumed by non-element attributes of the
> array object.

The following code:

```
x = np.zeros((3,5,2), dtype=np.uint64)
x[0].nbytes
```

Outputs:

```
80
```

Why?

Again from `numpy` documentation:

```
numpy.uint64: 64-bit unsigned integer
```

Comment: What output did you expect? I'm actually just curious, your question is clear.

Comment: Actually, I expect 64 bits or 8 bytes.

Comment: [`x[0].dtype.itemsize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.itemsize.html) to compare the different attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python (an in general), [one int64 consumes 8 bytes of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469553/python-memory-consumption-in-64-bit-system-for-int-and-float).

Slicing `x[0]` you get 10 elements:

```py
x[0]
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0]], dtype=uint64)

x[0].size
10
```

`10*8` is `80`, all is logical, no?